# What is the difference between "10%" and "10 percentage points"?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-3

Throughout the game I've seen a few dozen things use these, and they're probably not interchangeable, but what is the difference? For example, in a Soul Tree, I see:

- **Block Rate Up** - Boosts Block Rate by 10%
- **Block Rate Up** - Increases Block Rate by 15 percentage points.

A quick read of those would lead me to believe they're the same effect, but what is the difference here?

Comment: Would you mind providing screenshots for comparisons?

Comment: I have never played this game, but in mathematics this is a common way to differentiate multiplicative from additive percentage scaling.  In other words, two "50 percentage points" bonuses would combine to +100%, while two "50% bonus"es would combine to 1.5*1.5=2.25, or a total of "125% bonus".  However I'm not making this an answer because it could just be an error in translation.

Comment: @Wondercricket I certainly can get screenshots, but there are no visual differences on those screens, just text, which is why I didn't add any.

Comment: It works as BlueRaja said. You can check that with accessories having the same kind of descriptions. I'll write an answer with screenshots when I can make some, if nobody made an answer by then.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft [This](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/357204-xenoblade-chronicles-3/80113729) GameFaqs post seems to back that up

Comment: I'd support whoever makes it into an answer! Thanks folks. Learned something new today regardless!

Comment: +10% = 50% -> 55%; +10 %age points = 50% -> 60%

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As explained in comment, the first one multiplies the statistic by the value, while the second adds a flat value to the statistic.

Example with 2 accessories (one gives block rate, the other physical def, but the formulation is different).

- This first one boosts block rate by 32%. As you can see, I get a bonus of 32% of 27 = 8% block rate (rounded down, since 27 * 32% = 8.64).

[image: Sena with 32% percent]

- This second one increases my physical defense by 6 percentage points. As you can see, I get a flat increase from 48% to 54%.

[image: Sena with 6 percentage points]

It works the same with gems and the Soul tree.

Comment: If someone has pictures in english, feel free to edit, as it doesn't seem I can change the game language (only the audio from english to japanese)

Comment: I uploaded English photos (Since I'm allergic to French ;) ), and altered the text to account for the different items and values. I also added a small info regarding calculations. Please let me know if I missed anything

Comment: @Wondercricket I changed an old mention of the critical rate you left (since now it's block rate and physical def), but the rest is perfect.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for catching the one I missed. I posted a [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/398617/124566) regarding the rounding I noticed