# Do accessories round attributes changes, or do they hold onto decimal values?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-3

While providing English screenshots for [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/398534/124566) answer (per the suggestion/request of the author), the accessory I was using provided a 32% Block Rate increase on a value of 27. Mathematically, 32% of 27 is 8.64. When the boost in displayed on the screen, it rounds the 8.64 down to just 8.

[image]

Does the system actually round this boost to 8%, or does the system hold onto the .64% increase behind the scenes (meaning if I were to apply another accessory that increased a fraction of a percentage, would the system combine the .64% with say .36% and apply an additional 1% in total)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reaching level myself (this is unlocked after reaching lv30), I was able to play around with various accessories. Below is what I have discovered

1. Accessories that provide a percentage boost increases it based on your classes **base HP**. At first I thought the games calculations were broken or my calculations were wrong. However after some trail and error, I realized the HP increase did not include the increase provided by gems.
2. Piggy backing off the first, the percentage increase does not stack. As shown in the images below, the increased value on the summary screen is 31% and 20% of 2617 respectively and not chained amounts

[image: 20% HP increase]
[image: 31% HP increase]

3. Thirdly, the premise of the question ended up being moot in the end as the game does not allow you to equip multiple accessories that provide the same boost

[image: not allowed same boost]